# adb pull file from /data/data

Tags: rooting, file-system

Using adb with a rooted mobile, a common method to pull files only accessible to root (like the ones in /data/data) is moving those files with root to the SDCard attached to the mobile (which is formated with FAT32 and thus doesn't have file permission restrictions) and then *adb pull* those files from the SDCard.

The problem arises when the used device doesn't have a SDCard slot (as the moto G first genereation), so is it possible to pull to the host some files located in the directory /data/data (which is only accessible with root) without using an SDCard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible if the ADB daemon on the device runs with root privileges – which can be achieved e.g. using chainfire's [adbd Insecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd):

[image: adb Insecure]
<sup>*adbd Insecure* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd); click image to enlarge)</sup>

Another possibility would be setting `ro.secure` to `0` in the `build.prop` or `default.prop`. To my experience, `adbd` does not honor this on all devices/ROMs.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the solution posted by Izzy, I've been able to *adb pull* a file located in the /data/data directory of the phone to the host by first copying it to the directory /system/media (which is reachable to the shell user) and once there, changing its file permissions to make it readable by *others*. For example to pull the contacts database file to the host the procedure would be:

```
host $ adb shell
mobile $ su
mobile # mount -o remount,rw /system
mobile # cd /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases
mobile # cp contacts2.db /system/media/
mobile # cd /system/media/
mobile # chmod 755 contacts2.db
mobile # mount -o remount,ro /system
mobile # exit
mobile $ exit
host $ adb pull /system/media/contacts2.db
```

Note: I've tested it on a Motorola Moto G first generation (which lacks SDCard slot).